# GeForce Experience ignores taskbar on secondary monitors in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, taskbar, nvidia-geforce

NVIDIA's GeForce Experience program in a Windows 8/8.1 environments will ignore the taskbars on secondary monitors and fullscreen over the top of them, similar to how Windows 7 and prior didn't have one. Does anyone know exactly why this is or, preferably, how I can force the program to fullscreen with the taskbar beneath it still showing?

**Edit**: Here's a couple of screenshots. First, with GFE on the primary monitor, second with on the other. You can see in the second picture that the status bar on the bottom is actually behind the window.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you meant exactly?

Comment: Updated with images.